# Custom WPF Calendar Inside a DatePicker

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker, custom-controls

I've created a custom Usercontrol based on the Calendar control. I would like to use this calendar as the popup control within a datepicker, though it is not a style thus:

```
    CalendarStyle="{StaticResource customCalendar}"
```

Does not work.
Is there anyway to do this without having to create an entire custom DatePicker?

Comment: You want to change the `Style` of the calendar, which is in `DatePicker`?

Comment: I created a calendar that includes extra buttons and a stackPanel. I did this using a custom control. If there is a way to do it just with styling I would more than happily do that, but I am unaware of how too.

Comment: To say exactly show your code of custom control. If the calendar style is `normal`, it sets without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution, I can actually easily do this using styling.

```
            <Style x:Key="CustomCalendar" TargetType="Calendar">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="PART_Root" Background="LightGray">
                        <CalendarItem Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}" Name="PART_CalendarItem" Style="{TemplateBinding Calendar.CalendarItemStyle}"/>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

then placing all other controls I wish to use within the stack panel.